# Filter files using a wildcard character (java)

Tags: java, file, wildcard

Using a wildcard character I want to process files in a directory. If a wildcard character is specified I want to process those files which match the wildcard char else if not specified I'll process all the files. Here's my code

```
   List<File> fileList;
   File folder = new File("Directory");
   File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if(prop.WILD_CARD!=null) {  
        Pattern wildCardPattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+prop.WILD_CARD+"(.*)?.csv",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        for(File file: listOfFiles) {
            Matcher match = wildCardPattern.matcher(file.getName());
            while(match.find()){
                String fileMatch = match.group();
                if(file.getName().equals(fileMatch))  {
                    fileList.add(file); // doesn't work
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        fileList = new LinkedList<File>( Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles()));
```

I'm not able to put the files that match wildcard char in a separate file list. Pls help me to modify my code so that I can put all the files that match wildcard char in a separate file list. Here I concatenate prop.WILD_CARD in my regex, it can be any string, for instance if wild card is test, my pattern is .*test(.*)?.csv. And I want to store the files matching this wildcard and store it in a file list.

Comment: I guess your pattern is not correct. You have to show the pattern and the file name you expect it to match

Comment: @IngoKegel No my pattern is right, it works. prop.WILD_CARD can be anything for instance if its test my pattern is .*test(.*)?.csv. And I want to store the files matching this wildcard and store it in a file list

Comment: The first thing is that your `fileList` is not initialized. The second one is to print the `file.getName()` and `fileMatch` to the Console before you compare them.

Comment: You also don't need the `while (match.find())` part. It can be replaced with `if (match.matches()) fileList.add(file)`

Comment: @svz I did the comparison and names match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this code and it runs pretty well. You should check for logical errors somewhere else.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String WILD_CARD = "";
     List<File> fileList = new LinkedList<File>();
       File folder = new File("d:\\");
       File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if(WILD_CARD!=null) {  
            Pattern wildCardPattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+WILD_CARD+"(.*)?.mpp",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            for(File file: listOfFiles) {
                Matcher match = wildCardPattern.matcher(file.getName());
                while(match.find()){
                    String fileMatch = match.group();
                    if(file.getName().equals(fileMatch))  {
                        fileList.add(file); // doesn't work
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
            fileList = new LinkedList<File>( Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles()));

        for (File f: fileList) System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

This returns a list of all *.mpp files on my `D:` drive.

I'd also suggest using

```
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            Matcher match = wildCardPattern.matcher(file.getName());
            if (match.matches()) {
                fileList.add(file);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works for me too!!! Prob is I didn't initialize fileList in the beginning and as you suggested I used if instead of while. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into the FilenameFilter class and see if it helps simplify your code. As for your regex expression, I think you need to escape the "." character for it to work.

Comment: Actually I don't have prob with my Regex, only thing is I don't know how to put the matched files in a separate file list.